# gulp undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, gulp, gulp-uglify

Here i m new to node, angular , gulp. I m using gulp to generate minify files all the stuff while i m running the gulp task it is given me the error

[image]

Below is my gulpfile.js code

```
gulp.task('dev', function(){
var builtPartialDev = gulp.src(paths.partials)
    .pipe(plugins.htmlhint({'doctype-first':false}))
    .pipe(plugins.htmlhint.reporter())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDev));

var buitStyleDev = gulp.src(paths.styles)
    .pipe(plugins.less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDev));

var builtAppScriptsDev = gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(plugins.jshint())
    .pipe(plugins.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDev))
    .pipe(plugins.angularFilesort());

var builtVendorScriptsDev = gulp.src(bowerFiles())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDevBowerComponents))
    .pipe(plugins.order(['jquery.js', 'angular.js', 'angular-ui.js', 'ui-bootstrap.js', 'ui-bootstrap-tpls.js']));


var builtIndexDev = gulp.src(paths.index)
    .pipe(plugins.htmlhint())
    .pipe(plugins.htmlhint.reporter())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.distDev))
    .pipe(plugins.inject(builtVendorScriptsDev, {relative:true, name:'bower'}))
    .pipe(plugins.inject(builtAppScriptsDev, {relative:true}))
    .pipe(plugins.inject(buitStyleDev, {relative:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDev));

return es.merge(builtIndexDev, builtPartialDev) 

});
```

Comment: which line is line 27?

Comment: if you use gulp load-plugins, you need to npm install and declare it too, `var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();`

Comment: .pipe(plugins.htmlhint({'doctype-first':false}))  this is line 27

Comment: thanks YOU that syntax work for me i forgot to add "()"  -- the right syntax is var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

Answer (score 0):

You need to require gulp in your gulpfile. Add the following line to your file:

`var gulp = require('gulp')`

You will probably also have to install gulp for your project which you can do with `npm install --save gulp`.

If you don't have npm I suggest you look into how to install and use it.

Comment: i already added all the required initialisation at the top itself pavan...i didn't display here and installed gulp also ...if not we will error there itself rgt